# How to connect to a HTTP server in Docker container on a remote host?

Tags: docker, networking

I want to run a Web server (nginx-based) in a container on a machine on the local network, access it over this network. It's working fine on the local machine, but I can't figure out how to get into it from another machine.
I've tried:

sudo docker network create hyperdata-network

sudo docker network inspect hyperdata-network

gives me an IP of 172.18.0.2, which I can ping.

Next I tried to attach the nginx-based container (called hyperdata-static) to the network:

sudo docker run -itd --name hyperdata --network=hyperdata-network --hostname=hyperdata -p 80:80 hyperdata-static

but I can't see port 80, and the docs have got me hopelessly confused.

Ideally I'd also like to address the Web server by name.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is your local machine accessible from the remote host? (try pinging the ip address of the host machine from remote machine) If it is accessible, try hitting http://<hostmachine's IP>:80 ( you don't have to give port 80 explicitly as http default is port 80)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I was overcomplicating things trying the Docker network stuff, exposing the port was enough.

Comment: I will add it as an answer then. cool

Comment: Please add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you local machine accessible from the remote host? (try pinging the ip address of the host machine from remote machine) If it is accessible, try hitting http://hostmachine'sIP:80/ ( you don't have to give port 80 explicitly as http default is port 80). If the machine is accessible and not the port 80, then look for possible firewall restrictions.